# What can I do about a "missing mcp.cfg" error?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I am trying to use [MCP](http://mcp.ocean-labs.de/page.php?4). After trying to run `decompile.sh`, I manually ran `decompile.py`, getting the error "`ERROR:root:!! Missing mcp.cfg !!`"

I tried to copy the variables from `mcp.cfg` into the files which reference them, but I still got the error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the file `mcp.cfg` can't be found. Normally this would mean you've deleted it, or you have a bad install of MCP that doesn't contain the file and should re-download it.

However, you mention that you have thought about copying variables from it, so that suggest to me that you do actually have the file on your disk and have seen it.

You also mention having "manually run" the `decompile.py` script, and that is, I think, your problem. You're probably running the script from a working directory that is unexpected (not the root of the MCP installation) and thus your `mcp.cfg` file isn't being found where the scripts think it should should be relative to that current working directory.

Run the script from the proper working directory; consult the documentation or the official website for additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem but I was able to get MCP running! Open terminal and type "cd (insert mcp dir here)" no quotes obviously. Then, type in "bash" and hit enter. Finally, "./(script name).sh", hit enter and Done! It took me a few hours of a sleepless night to figure this out, but now that I have, hacking is on!

Comment: EmeraldGamer51, I tried what you said exactly (we are on mac, yes??) and I got this from terminal: env: python2: No such file or directory Please Help!!!